# Not able to retrieve an email's body with TextBody

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

Previously was using OpenPop for testing email notifications. Switched over to IMAP and started looking at MailKit today. I am currently having a problem retrieving the plain string text for the body of an email from Gmail.

A snippet of my code so far:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    var uri = new Uri("imaps://imap.gmail.com");

    client.Connect(uri);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
    client.Authenticate(credentials);
    client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    var inboxMessages = client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full).ToList();

    foreach (var message in inboxMessages)
    {
        var messageBody = message.TextBody.ToString();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

From what I understand of the documentation so far TextBody can retrieve the body of the message in plain text if it exists. However while debugging in Visual Studio I see this is the value for TextBody.

{("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "utf-8" "FORMAT" "flowed") NIL NIL "7BIT" 6363 NIL NIL NIL NIL 119)}

Is there a step I am missing somewhere? Does this mean the body is missing from MailKit's perspective? I see a similar value for HtmlBody as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `Fetch` method only fetches *summary* information about the message, as in, the information you need to construct a message-list in a mail client.

If you want to fetch the *message*, you need to use the `GetMessage` method.

Like this:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");
    client.Authenticate ("username", "password");

    client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    var uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.All);

    foreach (var uid in uids) {
        var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage (uid);
        var text = message.TextBody;

        Console.WriteLine ("This is the text/plain content:");
        Console.WriteLine ("{0}", text);
    }

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

Now, if you want to download *only* the message body, you'd need to *use* the summary information that you were fetching and pass that in as an argument to the `GetBodyPart` method like this:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");
    client.Authenticate ("username", "password");

    client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    // Note: the Full and All enum values don't mean what you think
    // they mean, they are aliases that match the IMAP aliases.
    // You should also note that Body and BodyStructure have
    // subtle differences and that you almost always want
    // BodyStructure and not Body.
    var items = client.Inbox.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);

    foreach (var item in items) {
        if (item.TextBody != null) {
            var mime = (TextPart) client.Inbox.GetBodyPart (item.UniqueId, item.TextBody);
            var text = mime.Text;

            Console.WriteLine ("This is the text/plain content:");
            Console.WriteLine ("{0}", text);
        }
    }

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

You can think of the `Fetch` method as doing a SQL query on your IMAP server for the metadata for your messages and the `MessageSummaryItems` enum argument as a bitfield where the enum values can be bitwise-or'd together to specify which `IMessageSummary` properties you want to be populated by the `Fetch` query.

In the above example, the `UniqueId` and `Body` bitflags specify that we want to populate the `UniqueId` and `Body` properties of the `IMessageSummary` results.

If we want to get information about read/unread status, etc - we'd add `MessageSummaryItems.Flags` to the list.

Note: both the `Body` and the `BodyStructure` enum values populate the `IMessageSummary.Body` property, but `BodyStructure` includes more info that is needed to determine if a body part is an attachment or not, etc.